# Does PHP feature built-in memoization

Tags: php

Does PHP cache the result of functions? If so, with what versions and under what scenarios?

When I search for memoization support in PHP, there's a ton of suggestions on how to manually implement it but no definitive answer on if it's a built-in feature.

Comment: No, there is no built-in memoization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not the result of function calls. But if parse time counts and opcache is enabled, then the parse result like function definitions are memorized in their opcache representation. Given the function is pure, we could assume: partially for every result it is built in.

If we now consider the result of an `include` statement, it gets towards that and then sometimes interesting if such an include returns strings that may have become part of the opcache. This is undocumented and unspecified behaviour.